# How to link CSS to HTML on Github

Tags: html, css, github

I have been trying to code a website, however, my CSS link is not working as my website only displays my HTML. I was wondering if I had linked it incorrectly or if there was a specific way I have to link for Github.

Thank you!

index.html

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style copy.css/">
```

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtNWc.png)

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: your missing a `"` `<link rel="icon" href="assets/images/icon.jpg>` which is the line above your CSS

Comment: you cannot use spaces in the filename. rename the file as style_copy.css or style-copy.css or whatsoever that avoid the space in the middle

Comment: Could also be the path - without a leading forward slash like `/assets/css...` then you have created what is called a "relative link". To illustrate: if I am currently on mywebsite.com/foo/bar with that link tag included, it would attempt to include the file as `mywebsite.com/foo/assets/css/...`. With a leading forward slash, it would always be linking to `mywebsite.com/assets/css/...`

Comment: Use href="./assets/and/so/on"

the ./ just means it's located in the same folder